# Generating Location data for nodes in MANET for use in Machine Learning algorithms

Tags: network-programming, simulation, ns2

I want to run some location prediction algorithms for MANETs, so I want to have a data set from network simulations.

The reference I'm using told that the data should be generated with two different mobility models:

- The Random Waypoint Mobility model (RWM): using the ns-2’s setdest tool
- The Reference Point Group Mobility model (RPGM): using the BonnMotion tool

the data should be in the form:

> [Current time - latest x – latest y – latest update time – previous x
>   – previous y – previous update time]

for each node.

I don't know how to do so with ns-2.

Comment: 1) Random-Way-Point-Mobility-Model https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+setdest+random+waypoint → → http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/tutorial/nsscript7.html , etc. 2) RPGM, please read the Bonnmotion Manuel  https://sys.cs.uos.de/bonnmotion/doc/README.pdf

Comment: `[Current time - latest x – latest y – latest update time – previous x – previous y – previous update time]` :  Google https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q==ns2+[Current+time+-+latest+x+%E2%80%93+latest+y+%E2%80%93+latest+update+time+%E2%80%93+previous+x+%E2%80%93+previous+y+%E2%80%93+previous+update+time] ... A few hits, not much relevant?

Comment: I went through what you told me, I edited the tcl script output by ns2 setdest, and the tcl script is now: https://pastebin.com/8eymJuq8

I am trying to run the tcl script but it logs errors, and here's the log:
https://pastebin.com/QYAdtyRM

would you help?

Comment: Unknown(.tcl) : Not a real simulation file. Mostly a scen file. Please read  the tested manet examples carefully, to know the connected scen file, etc.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNR0ZuQ1l6YnlWRGc/view?usp=sharing , ref. your other thread. And please run the examples. ..... ..... Note : setdest is **not** creating a tcl file, but a scenario / movement file.

Comment: it worked ! many thanks for your support.
I have another question:

here's the output file (movement trace)
https://pastebin.com/zK0xyxAB

I don't know what does the last value in each line represent?

Comment: May be you can find something here http://www.grc.upv.es/Links/local/griswoldNS-2%20Traces.htm ... Or in my "tracefile links" https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNeS1weGNuVWwwLWc/view?usp=sharing → tracefile-doc.tar.gz